# current between Linked list and BST - java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

Is it possible to convert a linked list to binary search tree BST.
and also have a link between them in a way of the current element, is pointing to the same in both linked list and BST

linked list :

```
 3 , 5 ,6 ,1, 2 ,0,4
```

BST :

```
     3
   /    \
  1      5
 /  \    / \
0   2   4   6
```

when current of the binary search tree points to 1
it should also point to 1 in the linked list

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you need a left/right reference as well as a prev/next reference?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can use the same nodes in both data structures. The nodes would then each have the two links of their "linked-list-ness" and the two children of their "BST-ness".

So as a quick example, a node might have fields like this:

```
class Node {
    public Node next, prev; // for the linked list
    public Node left, right; // for the BST
    // put some data in here too
}
```

It takes some care to use those nodes, because it's easy to get the two data structures "out of sync", for example if you remove a node from one but forget to remove it from the other. Then again, maybe that's what you want. But other things stay the same, for example if you do rotations in the BST then you don't have to touch the linked-lists fields at all, and similarly if you swap two nodes in the linked-list then the BST fields are not affected at all. So in those cases the code will be the same as it would have been if you had a normal kind of node that is part of only one data structure.

Of course this trick does not apply to the standard library implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely have that as harold pointed out above. And as he also points out, you can get them out of sync if your implementation has bugs that allow the data structures to go out of sync.

So, you could do this instead:

```
//YourBST.java
public class YourBST<T> {
  public List<T> toList() { //Convert this to a list }
}

//YourList.java
public class YourList<T> {
  public YourBST<T> toBST() { //... }
}
```

And then, when modifying one or the other..just call the conversion methods to set the other datastructure.

```
YourBST<String> bst = new YourBST<String>();
YourList<String> list = new YourList<String>();

modify(bst); //modify your BST in some way
list = bst.toList();

modify(list); //modify your List in some way
bst = list.toBST();
```

Edit: if you indeed want the same object to have prev/next references as well as left/right references, that still requires the node class as Harold described above. This solution simply fixes the "out of sync" problem.